# Why isn't my port forwarding with mysql working on my server?

Tags: ssh, mysql, port-forwarding

I have a mysql server running on some server in our network. Now, only connections from localhost are accepted by the server and I can't connect to it remotely. Now, I want to set up a port forwarding, using ssh to be able to use some GUI tools with this server. However, somehow I can not get authenticated, when I connect via tunnel! It goes like this:

On the remote machine:

```
mysql -u exporter --password=test -h localhost -P 3306 mydatabase
```

Everything works perfectly and I get a connected mysql shell.

Now, on my local machine, to set up port forwarding:

```
ssh remotemachine -L127.0.0.1:33066:127.0.0.1:3306
```

TO connect to the remote mysql server, using this tunnel, on the local machine I do:

```
mysql -u exporter --password=test -h localhost -P 33066 mydatabase
```

Here is the error I get:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'exporter'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How is that even possible and what can I do about it?
Note: the problem is totally reproducible with another mysql server on another remote machine.

Comment: Have you check the MySQL logs to see if they provide any additional useful info?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the logs about this connection, which is kinda odd too. At least I can't find any in /var/log/mysql/whatever.log. May be the server was configured this way, I don't know.

Comment: What if you remove the embedded password (`test`), so make MySQL prompt you for it? Then maybe you can see *if* MySQL is accepting the connection to start with. (As MySQL allows for password-less accounts, I assume that any prompt for credentials is really initiated by the server.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try using

```
ssh -L 33066:localhost:3306 remotemachine
```

?

Please make also sure that inside the mysql privilege system, both 127.0.0.1 and localhost are allowed sources for your database user.

Comment: Hmmm, SQLSTATE 28000 is "Invalid authorization specification", so I guess the connection is fine. Still, *maybe* "Access denied" might indeed also indicate it simply cannot connect at all. For debugging, one might also compare `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:33066:www.google.com:80 remotemachine` to `ssh -L 33066:www.google.com:80 remotemachine` and then see where `http://localhost:33066` takes one.

Comment: Yes, removing 127.0.0.1 from tunnel specification is no good. Result is the same.

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem: forwarding the port to google worked as expected...
Do you know, where at least I can find more details about this error? This failed connection attempt must have been logged somewhere, mustn't it?

Comment: Is you local mysql user allowed to connect from 127.0.0.1 and localhost inside the mysql privilege system (maybe it's just a name vs IP issue) ?

Comment: @Dominik OH MY GOD!!! It worked!!! It is unbelievable, never even thought of that, thank you!

I'm accepting your answer, but please edit it to include this solution.

Comment: @maksymko I just added the info about the mysql privilege system to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just tried to do the same myself today and found out that when you connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 the client automaticaly tries to connect to the process via a local socket instead of a normal tcp/ip connection, wich avoids the ssh tunnel.

You have to instead use your local network address (ex.: 192.168.0.35) instead of the loopback device address(127.0.0.1).

You will also need to add the -g parameter to your ssh command line to make that port forward available via non-loopback-device address 192.168.0.35:3306, otherwise it would just be available via 127.0.0.1:3306

Answer (score 0):

Cross-post of this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/966471/522755)

I had a similar issue, and per this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12568665/4146923), the solution was removing the 'any' user.

It seems that MySQL sees a difference between a user connecting via localhost and 127.0.0.1, which is part of the issue if I understand it correctly.

---